# How pass GCP parameters/arguments via spark sql job to hive sql

Tags: hive, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

i'm trying to run a hive task using DataprocSubmitJobOperator at airflow. here i want to pass the database and other variables(like Date etc) values from hive task to hive sql to run query dynamically. I tried using map and setvariable but is not supported.
what is the correct method to pass the values.

```
HIVE_EXE_TASK={
  "reference": {"project_id":project_id},
  "placement": {"cluster_name":CLUSTER_NAME},
  rk_sql_job": {"query_file_uri":{"queries":["set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict"]},
  "query_file_uri": f"gs://{BUCKET}/hql/event.hql",
   "properties":{"spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy":"LEGACY","spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold":"-1"}},
}
```